# Python 2.7 special splunk object to dataframe conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i am reading some data from splunk and i want to convert that format to pandas dataframe.

[Splunk blog question](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/439510/how-to-convert-intersplunks-readresults-to-datafra.html#utm_campaign=0-welcome-exit&utm_source=onboard&utm_medium=popup&utm_content=selcukozer)

```
result = results.ResultsReader(service.jobs.export(SEARCH_COMMAND))
for rr in result:
    print(rr)

OrderedDict([('H', '123'), ('U', 'aaa@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537360524/-86840158')])
OrderedDict([('H', '456'), ('U', 'sss@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367876/-765151654')])
OrderedDict([('H', '145'), ('U', 'ddd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367571/540003017')])
OrderedDict([('H', '111'), ('U', 'asd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537376045/540216322')])
OrderedDict([('H', '222'), ('U', 'asd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537383484/-86104258')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame` accepts a list of dictionaries directly.

You can create a list via `lst = list(result)` and build the dataframe as below.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

lst = [OrderedDict([('H', '123'), ('U', 'aaa@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537360524/-86840158')]),
       OrderedDict([('H', '456'), ('U', 'sss@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367876/-765151654')]),
       OrderedDict([('H', '145'), ('U', 'ddd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367571/540003017')]),
       OrderedDict([('H', '111'), ('U', 'asd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537376045/540216322')]),
       OrderedDict([('H', '222'), ('U', 'asd@global-bilgi.entp'), ('S', 'motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537383484/-86104258')])]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

print(df)

#      H                      U                                             S
# 0  123  aaa@global-bilgi.entp   motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537360524/-86840158
# 1  456  sss@global-bilgi.entp  motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367876/-765151654
# 2  145  ddd@global-bilgi.entp   motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537367571/540003017
# 3  111  asd@global-bilgi.entp   motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537376045/540216322
# 4  222  asd@global-bilgi.entp   motv:SMP_SESSION_ID/1523537383484/-86104258
```